# Zurb Foundation Docs and Demo site - Create local copy?

Tags: zurb-foundation

Zurb broke their documentation site for V4.3.2 of Foundation.  Unfortunately, I have a site using that version that can't be upgraded.  I need ongoing, reliable access to see the docs and examples/demos for that version.  Is there a way to install those on my own system, like Telerik allows you to do that with their controls?

That way I wouldn't have to depend on Zurb keeping the docs working for old versions of Foundation.

https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/4.3.2/

Answer (score 0):

For a short term fix I used the web archive:

https://web.archive.org/web/20161120155204/http://foundation.zurb.com:80/sites/docs/v/4.3.2/

to access the site.

Once Zurb gets their site back up, I'll update this answer if I figure out how to duplicate their doc site locally.

Comment: So it looks like Zurb is never going to fix the V4 documentation--I just checked and it is even more broken.  I didn't choose to use Foundation for this project, but I'm stuck with this version of Foundation and it definitely makes me inclined to be anti-Zurb for any future projects.